# sqlite lookup by rowid perf

Tags: sqlite, database-performance

I red the "Query Planning" link https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html with great interest.

I'm still a beginer at sqlite3 and I'd like to ask a question regarding the performance of "lookup by rowid" technic.

The document say that a bsearch is done on the rowid, in my case I use a PK as rowid.

I use table with sparse PK values, once those table are constructed they never change again, no more insert/delete. I dunno if there is any API to 'close' a table, i.e make it non modifiable anymore.

Then I need to construct some index on the table on some cols. The document say that when searching in an index we are doing a primary bsearch on the INDEX, then we got a rowid then we do a secondary bsearch on the ROWID index to find the row.

Since the tabke is 'closed' while building the index does the optimiser could store not the rowid but instead the row_index avoiding the secondary bsearch.

=======================================
Along this line, if not using a PK, letting the rowid growing 1 by 1 during my table construct, whence it is closed and an INDEX created on it, does the rowid find on an INDEX bsearch match is used as in index into the table avoiding the secondary bsearch, if so I could organize my table in such way.

Thanx in advance for any advices
Cheers,
Phi

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a row_index.

To avoid the table lookup, put all the columns read by the query into the index so that you have a [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx).
Alternatively, use a [WITHOUT ROWID](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) table.